# Cant enable service with systemctl

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I made this service:

```
#!/bin/bash
node ../../home/NodeServer/server.js
```

All it should do is start the server on bootup, so i wanted to do

```
sudo systemctl enable startServer.service
```

But I got this error:

```
startServer.sh.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-insall.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable startServer.sh
update-rc.d: error: startServer.sh Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

When i try to do

```
sudo systemctl start startServer.service
```

it works like intended.

Comment: Did you check how a systemctl unit file should look? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solve it typing again the file because it seems that there was a strange character that was broken the parser. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute a script, which is not the same as a service.

You can make a file called `startServer.service` and write the following into it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start server that does a thing

[Service]
ExecStart=node /home/NodeServer/server.js
```

If you want to enable the service, do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /home/NodeServer/startServer.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

and now you should be able to start the service.